# Geofencing a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation, rubygems, geofencing

I am working on a web application using Ruby on Rails that allows employees to clock in and clock out when they arrive and leave work.

I am trying to find a way to allow users only to clock when they are within certain perimeter of the workplace. I have all the functionality of the clock in and out system working I just want to restrict people outside of certain radius to not use this feature.

Comment: I guess this has to do with the clocking device setup. Your clocking system should have all the software embedded to do this. And maybe an API to ping it from your Rails App.

Comment: My clocking set up is pretty basic. When the user clicks the "clock in" button a record is created with this time in my data base. Then when the user clicks "clock out" a record is created in the DB as well. I want to know if there is any way in which I can check if the user is within certain radius so let the user clock in or out if not display a message.

Comment: You could use the browser to get current geolocation of the user https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API but keep in mind that users can fake their location, I don't think you gain to much on that restriction, it's too easy to bypass.